# how can I find an upper bound and a lower bound for this recursive relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

However hard I try I can't use the master theorem to solve this relation.
Is there a way to do this. Any other ideas?

T(n,m) = T(n-1,m)+T(n,m-1)+1